# Get Attribute names using SPARQL from DBpedia

Tags: sparql, owl, dbpedia

I have a query that gets some objects and attributes.
For example

```
PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
SELECT DISTINCT * {
?company a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Company> . 
OPTIONAL { 
?company <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/industry> ?industry . 
}
OPTIONAL { 
?company <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/revenue> ?revenue_ . 
}
OPTIONAL { 
?company <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/homepage> ?homepage_ . 
}
OPTIONAL { 
?company <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/industry> ?industry_ . 
}
OPTIONAL { 
?company <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/location> ?location_ . 
}
}LIMIT 200
```

I get some results, for example 
[image: SPARQL Result table]

But what I actually want is a simple String for the attributes. Something like

```
company         industry         revenue         homepage         location
Argonon         Digital media    5.0E7                            United Kingdom
```

How can I create a query to get the names of the properties?

Comment: As far as I understand from your example you want "names" of values (objects of triples), not the properties. If I understood right, you can get them by `<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/industry>/rdfs:label` but then if some don't have labels, you'll miss them in your results.

Comment: Thank you @IvoVelitchkov, this is exactly what I want. If you post that as an answer, I can vote on it and accept it if no one posts any better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to get the **rdfs:label** of some of those values.  You can do that by following the property and then **rdfs:label** with a property path.  You might also want to filter based on the language of the label.  One other issue with your query is that the **homepage** property should actually **dbp:property**, not **dbo:property**.  Once you do that, you end up with this query:

```sql
PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
SELECT DISTINCT * {
?company a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Company> . 
OPTIONAL { 
?company <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/industry>/rdfs:label ?industry . 
filter langMatches(lang(?industry),"en")
}
OPTIONAL { 
?company <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/revenue> ?revenue_ . 
}
OPTIONAL { 
?company <http://dbpedia.org/property/homepage> ?homepage_ . 
}
OPTIONAL { 
?company <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/industry>/rdfs:label ?industry_ . 
filter langMatches(lang(?industry_),"en")
}
OPTIONAL { 
?company <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/location>/rdfs:label ?location_ . 
filter langMatches(lang(?location_),"en")
}
}LIMIT 200
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20rdf%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%20%0D%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%20%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20*%20%7B%0D%0A%3Fcompany%20a%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FCompany%3E%20.%20%0D%0AOPTIONAL%20%7B%20%0D%0A%3Fcompany%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2Findustry%3E%2Frdfs%3Alabel%20%3Findustry%20.%20%0D%0Afilter%20langMatches%28lang%28%3Findustry%29%2C%22en%22%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AOPTIONAL%20%7B%20%0D%0A%3Fcompany%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2Frevenue%3E%20%3Frevenue_%20.%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AOPTIONAL%20%7B%20%0D%0A%3Fcompany%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2Fhomepage%3E%20%3Fhomepage_%20.%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AOPTIONAL%20%7B%20%0D%0A%3Fcompany%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2Findustry%3E%2Frdfs%3Alabel%20%3Findustry_%20.%20%0D%0Afilter%20langMatches%28lang%28%3Findustry_%29%2C%22en%22%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AOPTIONAL%20%7B%20%0D%0A%3Fcompany%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2Flocation%3E%2Frdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flocation_%20.%20%0D%0Afilter%20langMatches%28lang%28%3Flocation_%29%2C%22en%22%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%7DLIMIT%20200&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)